# How to declare RDF containers in RDF Schema?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

When writing an RDF schema, I can do the following to declare that a committee consists of a number of persons:

```
<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="Committee" />
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="members">
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Committee" />
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Person" />
</rdf:Property>
```

However, I have read that there is a fine semantic difference between defining individual persons as committee members as I did above, and the fact that only the whole group of given persons forms the committee. Hence, in such cases, one should consider using the RDF containers such as *rdf:Bag*.

My question is: **How to declare such a "bag of Persons" in the RDF schema?**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to declare that ONLY these people form the commitee, you should use `Collection`, not `rdf:Bag`. The RDF tutorial at w3schools.com gives an example:

https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_collectionvocab

In the RDF schema you need to declate a property "`hasMember`" or "`member`". Its *domain* is a commitee, and its *range* is a member. Then, the RDF file can describe an unlimited number of members for a given commitee. If in the commitee resource you want to specify that these are the ONLY memebrs, you use a `collection`. If you allow more members, use a `rdf:Bag`.

Note: This does not mean it's impossible to define a "bag of members" or "collection of members" as the range of a property. You can take a look at existing simple ontologies on the web (there are hundreds of them written in RDFS) and compare how they define a similar concept.